# Structure - subnav shows full nav, not sure why

Tags: templates, structure, navigation

*updated with EE and Structure Version*

EE 2.7.2 Structure 3.3.4

I'm building a site with structure and for each section of the site the child pages will be in the side bar so that if I'm on domain.com/about In the sidebar I will see:

About (h4 tag)

--sub page

--sub page

--sub page

However with the code (below) I"m using it output all entries for the entire site. Please advise.

```
{exp:structure:nav 
    css_class="side_navigation"
    start_from="/{segment_1}"
}
```

What I end up with however is

About

-- subpage

-- subpage

-- subpate

Services

-- subpage

-- subpage

etc...

Comment: which version of EE & Structure?

Comment: May be too obvious, but is there a value in the URL for segment_1?

Comment: dbigca - yes there is. Steven - EE 2.7.2 Structure 3.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved this, turns out it was a low variables/parse order issue. I needed to preparse segment_1 etc... on the main template. My code now looks like this

```
    {!--sidebar--}
    {exp:low_variables:single var="lv-sidebar"
      preparse:pre_seg_1="{segment_1}"
      preparse:pre_seg_2="{segment_2}"
      preparse:pre_seg_3="{segment_3}"
      preparse:pre_top_title="{structure:top:title}"
    }
```

And then in the Low Variable I have this:

```
<h4>{pre_top_title}</h4>

{if structure:child_ids != ''}
    {exp:structure:nav 
        css_class="side_navigation"
        start_from="/{pre_seg_1}"
    }
{/if}
```

Now weverything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the last version of Structure? 3.3.13
It seems that in version 3.3.12 a update was made for Nav tag output bug for ee 2.7

Francois

Comment: Worfoual, 3.3.13 is listed on devotee as the latest version, yet the version, I freshly installed last week for structure is 3.3.4 (higher number) so I'm not sure why that is or what would happen if I overwrote the existing higher version with the devotee downloaded version.

Comment: 3.3.13 is higher than 3.3.4 If you download 3.3.13 you will also get information about updating, you can find it also here: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/upgrading/

Comment: OKay - upgraded to 3.3.13 but the side nav is still not respecting the start from parameter.

Comment: did you run update?

Comment: yes, that was the first thing I did after uploading the files.